# Correct way to refer to a view in Android

Tags: java, android, comparative-review

What is the correct way of referring to a view (a) or (b).?

(a).

```
TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text);
textView.setText("Some Text");
```

(b).

```
((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText("Some Text");
```

I sometimes use the combination of both in my code. Will that affect my structure negatively in any way?

Is there any disadvantage / advantages when using any of those?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first is a *sequence of method calls*, the second is a *method call chain*. They are equivalent, so both are correct.

Which way is better really depends on the rest of your code.
For example, instead of this:

```
((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText("Some Text");
((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text)).append("more text");
((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text)).setOnClickListener(...);
```

This is clearly better:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text);
textView.setText("Some Text");
textView.append("more text");
textView.setOnClickListener(...);
```

It's better, because this does only one lookup in `rootView`, and it's also more compact.

On the other hand, if you only use the `TextView` once, then the chained call version is better, because you won't pollute your local scope with a variable you only use once, and it's more compact.

Sometimes I split chained calls for debugging purposes:
it can be hard to see which step failed in a long chain,
and easier to follow the execution step by step.